# Return a new tuple with combination of 2 parameters called by an function

Tags: python

In `Python`, I have a list say

```
t = ("ab","de","fg","jk")
```

**Make it so that the function above `append`I call returns a new tuple that is the combination of `tup` and `value` at the end of the new tuple. 
I am getting a list at end but i need  a tuple not an array.**

Please anyone help me with this, as i new to PYTHON

code part is :

```
t = ("ab","de","fg","jk")

def append(tup, value):
    return (tup+ value, value + tup)

append(*tuple)
```

After running above, i am getting `append argument after * must be iterable not type`

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Connor Make it so that the function above append call returns a new tuple that is the combination of tup and value at the end of the new tuple. I am getting a list at end but i need a tuple not an array

Comment: @pythonuser, please put a sample input and expected output.

Comment: the question asked to me was this 
Make it so that the function called returns a new tuple that is the combination of given parameters at the end of the new tuple. make sure a tuple is returned not an  array

So, I took input as 
Input I have given it is as 
 `t = ("ab","de","fg","jk")`
 `def append(tup, value):`

**after this I got stuck no idea how to proceed with **

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. What is your question? You can [edit] to clarify. Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) Also see [ask].

Comment: tuple is immutable and hence append should work like this to create entirely a new tuple
`('a','b')+tuple('c')`. Also you should pass `t` and not `tuple` which is a type

Comment: @wjandrea : I understand Sir , even I wrote the output but I am getting the error as
**can only concatenate tuple not str to tuple**

and my code was 
`t = ("abcd","nice","Curry","met")

def append(thetuple, value):
    tuple1=thetuple
    tuple2=value
    tuple3=tuple1+value
    return tuple3

appendtotuple(t, t)`

Comment: @AlainT. kudos to you sir ..wow it worked .thanks lot

Comment: @pythonuser I’m glad you got your question answered, b but please know for next time that this is not a well written question. Whenever you write a question you must include sample input and sample output (a description is not good enough). Please read the linked “How to ask a question” before posting your next question

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate tuples. There is also a convention for expressing a one value tuple so the return could be as simple as: `return tup + (value,)`